# Show Image on Select Change in MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a select list which contains some values representing status of some task.

The values for select list will come from a property in ViewModel. The object representing status also contains path of associate image like:

```
class Status
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public string ImagePath{get;set;}
}
```

Example values for **Rejected** status:

```
var s=new Status{ Id=1, Title="Rejected", ImagePath="~/images/rej.png"};
```

The image path is relative to root directory.

I want to display image representing the status on change of the select list in an image besides it. What is the best way to do this using  MVC3 Razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to store the reject image for each status?

I would have thought something like a reject image would be generic enough to be handled with Css and an image.

All you would do is change the class with javascript when the select is changed.

If you want to update data in the database on the change event then you can use ajax to post a change back.

Maybe I do not fully understand what it is you are trying to achieve.

But if I do then I would have thought the above would be an elegant way to handle the problem?

Comment: it is different image for each different status. CSS/JS way is okay and is old trick from webforms. I was just expecting something different for MVC/Razor :D

Comment: There might be a better way to do it, but I like keeping client work on the client if I can. I like the flexibility of javascript and ajax and when coupled with MVC3 its very powerful. Doing it without javascript in MVC wouldn't be any easier as there is no postback anymore(as there is in webforms). Arguably using JS is better because of a more fluent user experience. (that's my opinion anyways :) )